# SVD - reconstruction from U,S,V

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

I am learning some linear algebra for image compression and I am stuck at this point:

Suppose I have a matrix $R$,

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    5 & 7\\
    2 & 1\\\end{bmatrix} $$

Then I compute the covariance matrix s.t. $$\Sigma =\frac12R^TR$$
And I performed SVD with a Matlab function s.t. $ [U, S, V] = svd(\Sigma) $

I can see that $USV = \Sigma$ but how can I solve this equation below for $R$:
$\Sigma=\frac12R^TR$

Comment: You can't for $R =\begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and for $R=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, you have $\Sigma=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: @CharlesMadeline That is true, I just did the maths on paper and I see your point. What I was wondering about is, given $\Sigma = 1/2 R^T R$, how can I solve for $R$?

Comment: @michcs This comments just explained with a couterexample that you can't in general.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you, if I understand this correctly, if I perform an SVD on a covariance matrix to get $U, S, V$, I can only reconstruct the covariance matrix, but not the $R$ I used in $\Sigma = 1/2 R^T R$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Actually it has nothing to do with the SVD: once you compute $\Sigma=\frac12R^TR$, $R$ is lost, whatever you do on $\Sigma$, since the mapping $R\to R^TR$ is not injective.

Comment: Thank you! I've understood now.

Answer (score 0):

Given $\Sigma = \frac{1}{2}R^TR$, you first let $\Sigma = LL^T$. Find out $L$ by [Cholesky factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Now $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2(R^T)(R^T)^T=LL^T$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: The solution is not unique though, and quite probably not the original $R$.

Comment: Thank you, with the $R$ above, I computed $\Sigma$ to be;

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    14.5 & 18.5\\
    18.5 & 25\\\end{bmatrix} $$

and the cholesky factorization gives L as;

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
    3.8079 & 0\\
    4.8583 & 1.1813\\\end{bmatrix} $$

From $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2(R^T)(R^T)^T=LL^T$, it seems like I am back at the same problem of $R^T*R$, can you give me a little more guidance please?

Thank you -

Comment: Additionally, I have noticed that my toy example $R$ is non-Hermitian positive definite matrix. Suppose that I find the closest approximation to make it positive definite, how can I proceed?